# Ruby on Rails: How to use AWS Cognito pools to access S3 as a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm using AWS Cognito User Pool for authentication to my Ruby on Rails app. I've also created an Identity Pool for the User Pool, with the intention that logged in users are able to read files from a specific S3 bucket. However, I'm having trouble access objects in S3 as the logged in user. I have the tokens for the logged in user (`id_token`, `access_token`), but I don't know where to supply them.

Following the [sample code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-get-bucket-item.html) from the Ruby SDK doc only allows me to access S3 as a shared user, not the logged in user:

```rb
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: aws_region)
obj = s3.bucket('my-bucket').object('my-item')
obj.get(response_target: './my-code/my-item.txt')
```

Then I found [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenRuby.html) about using temporary credentials, but I also don't know how use the user's tokens anywhere. I've also tried STS' [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) that allows me to pass in the `id_token`, and used the Identity Pool's `role_arn`, but I'm getting `AccessDenied` error. I'm confused of the relationship between STS, IAM, and Cognito Identity Pool. Can anyone help?

Note: I've also enabled S3 access logging and it should log the Cognito user who access the files.